# Swift + macOS: Read a JSON file into a dictionary. During the process convert strings to dates and then sort by date

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have a swift program that reads in stock data in JSON format from multiple files.  One such file is laid out with a string date and an associated key value pair.  If there was a key for the string date I could create a struct with an init.  The code below allows me to read the file into a dictionary but I end up with a string where I want a date.  In addition, the only way I know how to sort is via mapping to a key value pair first which produces an array.  Any input that would point me in the right direction will be appreciated.
Below is a snippet of the JSON file and the code I use to read it into a dictionary.

Regards,

Chris

```
{
   "20200921": {
      "NAV": 173.67997
   },
   "20200922": {
      "NAV": 175.49292
   },
   "20200923": {
      "NAV": 171.35833
   },

struct TimeSeriesValue: Decodable {
    let value : Double
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value = "NAV"
    }
}
class getTimeSeriesData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var tmpData : [String:TimeSeriesValue] = [:]
    init() {
        getData()
    }
    func getData() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "JSONDataPrincipal", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.tmpData = try decoder.decode([String:TimeSeriesValue].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
struct JSONModelPrincipal {
   @ObservedObject var prinJSONData = getTimeSeriesData()
}
```

Comment: Your JSON tree has a closed curly bracket missing.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered hence why it maps to an array. So you probably don't want to use a dictionary if you need it to be ordered. And there is not much you can do here you need to use a dictionary. But nothing stops you from converting your `String` to a `Date` in your `getData()` function

Answer (score 1):

After some research and testing, I would agree that dictionaries are not designed for being ordered.  So, I modified the JSON file as shown below.  With this one line modification I have been able to create an init and convert the string to a date.  Thank you for the responses.

Chris

```
{ "Time Series Data" : {
    "20200921": {
        "NAV": 173.67997
    },
    "20200922": {
        "NAV": 175.49292
    },
```